# Пользователи www-data и FTP-акаунта

Tags: php, сервер

начал учить серверное развертывание. До конца не понял про `chmod`, `chown`... прошу объяснить:

на сервере, Apache\PHP работают от пользователя `www-data`, я создал ftp-аккаунт, и отдал его другу.. он зашел и создал там файл, допустим, `2.txt` и `PHP` ни в какую не хочет с ним работать, так как владельцем этого файла является этот `ftuser`, что и логично (тот, кто его создал)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    8 окт 18 07:06 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftpuser  ftpuser     0 окт 18 07:14 2.txt
```

а вот файл выше который стоит (1.txt), создан через пхп

я понимаю, что можно дать права в ручную, но хотелось, чтобы все было автоматизировано... чтобы с файлами мог работать и `php` и `ftp-user`

работает на `vsftpd`

хотя фтп аккаунт добавлен в группу...

```
root@serv:~# groups ftpuser
ftpuser : www-data
```

Comment: у Вас для группы права только на чтение: `-rw-r--r--`, потому и неважно что в группе пользователь есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работайте с групповыми правами.
Создайте общую группу, или используйте одну из существующих, например: `groupadd www-pub`

и добавьте в неё пользователей `www-data` и `ftpuser`

```
usermod -a -G www-pub www-data
usermod -a -G www-pub ftpuser
```

Смените группу для данной директории: `chgrp -R www-pub dir`
и выдайте права для нужные, например `chmod -R 774 dir`

После этого и апач и фтп должны иметь совместный доступ к директории.